# Installing gdal to geoserver running with apache tomcat

Tags: geoserver, gdal, apache, tomcat

I have been following Mastering GeoServer pdf from Colin Henderson to install gdal but didn't succeed. Here is what I did:

1. install Java, I've installed JRE windowsx64 (because my pc is x64)
2. install apache tomcat, I've decided to go with the version 8.5.13 instead of version 9 (because it would be more reliable) then I've installed apache-tomcat 8.5.13 via 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer. While installing I've ticked service startup and native and unticked documentation, host manager and example. I've configured tomcat, in Java section I've added following parameters ;

-Dserver 
-Xmx1024m 
-Xms512m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m

locahost:8080 is working now.

3. deploying geoserver to apache tomcat, I've downloaded GeoServer 2.11.0, war file from Geoserver's website.

[image: drag n drop]

localhost:8080/geoserserver/web Works now.

4. Installing the GDAL binary libraries; 
   From gisinternals, I have tried many of them over and over, none of them worked. For example I've downloaded complete versions of [image: these core and mrsid as mentioned]
   (I have c++2012 and c++2013 os my system)
   then set the environment variables as needed. Then applied this "To perform the installation, we just need to extract the .jar files contained within the archive into the WEB-INF/lib folder of our GeoServer installation."

it didn't work.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Same to Kenar: GDAL working fine with Geoserver on my server (IIS7 + Windows Server 2008) with Tomcat 8.0 and Geoserver 2.9 but now I've upgraded to Tomcat 8.5.15 and Geoserver 2.11.1, GDAL no longer works despite trying many combinations of libraries and builds. I've had previous experience of GDAL/Geoserver issues and with persistence usually solved the problem but getting nowhere with  Geoserver 2.11.1. GDAL works from the command line (>gdalinfo --formats displays the full range of raster formats). Is there a problem with Geoserver 2.11.1 and the available GDAL bindings? Do I revert back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoServer's GDAL extension is **very** picky about the version of GDAL you need - please follow the [instructions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#installing-gdal-native-libraries) in the [extension documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html).

This is due to the way the JAva to C(++) bindings work and to be honest is something of a mystery to Java developers but seems to keep the C++ boys happy.